# ruby on railsに関して、ransackを使ったactiverecordの検索について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

#### 解決したいこと

ransackを使ったサッカー選手検索機能を実装中です。
キーワードでの検索は成功するのですがactiverecordの検索ができません
フォームデータの送信はうまく行っているのですが、そこから先がわからないです。

#### 発生している問題・エラー

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: search_items_path do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name_cont, '選手検索' %>
<%= f.search_field :name_cont %>
<% f.label :category_id %>
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {}, {class:"select-box", id:"category"}) %>
<% f.label :country_id %>
<%= f.collection_select(:country_id, Country.all, :id, :name, {}, {class:"select-box", id:"country"}) %>
<br>
<%= f.submit '検索' %>
<% end %>
```

これが問題のコードです
nameのみにキーワードを入れた場合

```
Parameters: {"q"=>{"name_cont"=>"メッシ", "category_id"=>"0", "country_id"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"検索"}
```

こうなって検索に成功しますが、activerecordからキーワードを入れた場合

```
Parameters: {"q"=>{"name_cont"=>"", "category_id"=>"1", "country_id"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"検索"}
```

この場合検索に失敗します
全てのactiverecordに_contをつけた場合、nameにキーワードをれても検索に失敗します

カテゴリーのみ入れた時の検索と、文字を何も入れずに検索した時の挙動が同じです
そのためカテゴリーidを受け取るための何かが欠けているのだと思います
modelは
itemが

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
extend ActiveHash::Associations::ActiveRecordExtensions
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :minicategory
belongs_to :brand
end
```

categoryが

```
class Category < ActiveHash::Base
include ActiveHash::Associations
has_many :items

self.data = [
{ id: 0, name: 'カテゴリー選択' },
{ id: 1, name: 'キーパー' },
{ id: 2, name: 'ストライカー' },
]
end
```

playerのカラムは

```
id,name,category_id,country_id
```

categoryとcountryはactiverecordで実装しています。

```
Parameters: {"q"=>{"name_cont"=>"", "category_id"=>"1", "country_id"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"検索"}
```

このようにparameterのnameが空で、countryまたはcategoryの数値がある場合、countryが合致しているものを表示します。name、category、countryのどれかが合致していれば表示するとしたいため、部分一致検索の実装だと思います。

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#search-matchers をみても `*_id` という Predicate はないので、 `category_id` や `country_id` を完全一致で検索したいなら、パラメータは `q[category_id]` や `q[country_id]` ではなく以下のように `q[category_id_eq]` や `q[country_id_eq]` にする必要があるのではないでしょうか。

```
<% f.label :category_id_eq %>
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id_eq, Category.all, :id, :name, {}, {class:"select-box", id:"category"}) %>
<% f.label :country_id_eq %>
<%= f.collection_select(:country_id_eq, Country.all, :id, :name, {}, {class:"select-box", id:"country"}) %>
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます　Parameters: {"q"=>{"name_cont"=>"メッシ", "category_id_eq"=>"0", "country_id_eq"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"検索"}　label、カラム名を変更してみました。この場合メッシという名前が正しいですが、他のカラムが違っているため検索結果が出せていません

Comment: Parameters: {"q"=>{"category_id_eq"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"検索"}このように入力しないカラムを送信しない設定にすると期待される結果が出るため、「パラメーターがない場合送信しない」という設定にすればいけるのですがこれは多分不可能ですよね

Comment: Parameters: {"q"=>{"name_cont"=>”メッシ”, "category_id_eq"=>"1", “country_id_eq"=>”1”}, "commit"=>"検索"}

"name_cont"=>””
Parameters: {"category_id_eq"=>"1", “country_id_eq"=>”1”}, "commit"=>"検索"}

"category_id_eq"=>”0”
 
{"q"=>{"name_cont"=>”メッシ”, “country_id_eq"=>”1”}, "commit"=>"検索"}

“country_id_eq"=>”0”

Parameters: {"q"=>{"name_cont"=>”メッシ”, “country_id_eq"=>”1”}, "commit"=>"検索"} このようにパラメータを送信できればうまくいく気がします

Comment: 送信しない選択肢を入れるには `collection_select` に `prompt: true` か `include_blank: 'なし'` のように`include_blank:` を指定してみてください。https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select

Comment: 無事解決いたしました、ありがとうございました